# the output of the following code was "1.4E-45 3.4E24".why is 2e-45f being displayed as 1.4e-45?

Tags: java

```
class Test
{
public static void main(String [] args) {
  float a;
  a = 2e-45f;
  double b = 34e23;
  System.out.println(a + "  " + b); // prints "1.4E-45 3.4E24"
 }
}
```

this code was used to understand exponential notation in java.

Comment: What's `2e-45f` equal to and what do you **expect** the value of `a` to be displayed as?

Comment: Are you certain a float can represent the number `2e-45f` exactly ?

Comment: It's not a `double` but a `float`.

Comment: I suggest avoiding `float` has it has both a limited precision and to some degree a limited exponent (though the exponent is usually fine for most real problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float a;
a=2e-45f;
```

The value of `a` exceeds, or is lesser than the smallest number that a `float` can accept. Check it out [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html).

> MIN_VALUE - A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of
>   type float, 2^(-149).

`2^(-149) = ~1.4e-45`

Answer (score 0):

Floats cannot hold the value of all real numbers. If you need that kind of precision use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are beyond the range of float.

> float: 4 bytes, IEEE 754. Covers a range from 1.40129846432481707e-45 to 3.40282346638528860e+38 (positive or negative).

`a=2.0e-44f;` works fine.